# make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, makefile

i have a go lang project that run some commands with make like below :

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ ${1} == 'down' ]]; then
  echo "downing infrastructure"
  docker-compose -f ./deploy/docker-compose.infra.yml down
else
  echo "uping infrastructure"
  docker-compose -f ./deploy/docker-compose.infra.yml up -d
fi
```

so now i am calling this command to run this file :

```
make infra up
```

but when it tried to load file it gives the error below :

```
./scripts/infra.sh up
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, sh C:\Users\farsh\go\src\gojeh\scripts\infra.sh up, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:25: infra] Error 2
```

i though it may be problem with dockerfile locations so i tried another command that has the content like below :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "running ${1} ${2}"
cd ./services/${1} && go run ./cmd ${2}
```

but yet again i got the same error . i read on other topics to add some environment but i could not solve the problem with them

Comment: What `make` do you use? Do you have `sh` available anywhere? Please share output of `make --version` and `where.exe sh`.

Comment: `where.exe sh` gives me `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`

Comment: `make --version`  `GNU Make 4.3`

Comment: `make --version` gives this to get more details `GNU Make 4.3
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
`

Comment: So it cannot find `sh` and this is what the error message is about. Do you have `sh` installed anywhere? Does your `Makefile` set `SHELL`? Please investigate effective values with e.g. `make -p infra up | ? { $_ -match "SHELL" }` (PowerShell syntax).